# Eclipse Arduino IDE cant't find avr-g++ and avr-gcc

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino, avr, avr-gcc

I am trying to replace the Arduino IDE with the Arduino Eclipse plugin.
After downloading everything needed and trying to compile even the simplest "Hello World" - Program I get the following error in eclipse:

[image: error]

When calling:

```
which avr-gcc
```

in terminal it returns the correct directory, no problems here.

- Arduino eclipse plugin V2 (Eclipse Marketplace)
- Arduino IDE 1.6 (newest from homepage)
- Ubuntu 14.10
- Eclipse Luna

thx

Answer (score 1):

From Eclipse > Properties of project > Environment > add the variable A.RUNTIME.TOOLS.AVR-GCC.PATH

You could use XDAQ that provides a scientific ecosystem of powerfull tools with Arduino IDE + Eclipse Luna C++. See more here: [XDAQ](http://goo.gl/OOnqUK)

Answer (score 0):

You must do some configuration at Eclipse(project). In Eclipse are a Plugin fpr AVR, too.
Here are some links to tutorials, which can help to solve your problem:
http://www.timteatro.net/2012/03/22/beginning-atmel-avr-development-in-linux-using-avr-eclipse-avr-gcc-and-avrdude/

http://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-started-with-ubuntu-and-the-AVR-dragon/?lang=de

If you understand german:

http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/AVR_Eclipse

Comment: All your links refer to AVR Eclipse or avr-gcc directly, i am not using that but the "Arduino Eclipse IDE V2" plugin. Additionally I already have all the dependencies installed.

Comment: maybe you must do some configuration on the project properties itself and not just install dependencies

Comment: The only configuration you have to do is to set the path to the Arduino IDE and that's set up and working. Besides this plugin delivers a wizard for new arduino projects, so nothing obvious to set up here.

Answer (score 0):

Download arduino 1.6.0 and point your eclipse arduino ide path to that. 1.6.1 to 1.6.3 don't work with the plug in.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same problem on my all newly installed laptop ...

- Ubuntu 15.04 "vivid"
- Arduino 1.6.5
- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers 4.5.0
- AVR Eclipse plugin 2.4.1
- Arduino eclipse extensions 2.2.0.1

I used [this video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZJ6UH_V_fg) to install

I haven't tryed the @misteralex solution but if it work's it's cleaner than mine :-/

In my case, all avr binary are stored in /usr/bin, but Eclipse tool chain wants to use then from /bin . I want to create some links to do the substitution without moving binaries. But there is 28 binaries and I'm a little lazy so I use the commandline to create them :

```
cd /bin
for ff in `ls /usr/bin/avr-*` ; do ln -s $ff $(echo $ff | awk -F "/" '{ print $4 }') ; done
```

Now verify command from Eclipse give "Finished building target" message !